# Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant download

Tags: powershell

Anyone know where to download the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant?

My saved link no longer works and I can't seem to find the download (64-bit) anywhere via Google search or the Microsoft downloads site.

Here is the URL I used previously: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200202033155/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41950&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1

Comment: Thanks Doug. Since this module handles authentication I would much prefer to get this directly from Microsoft. Does anyone know if this has been deprecated and replaced by something else? Perhaps that is why Microsoft pulled it? Although I was able to still find the 32-bit version of this.

Comment: indeed - @Oremac answer is a great segue - you need to get https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-msonlinev1?source=recommendations&view=azureadps-1.0 which is Install-Module MSOnline

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the functionality in the Sign-In Assistant has been moved into the MSOnline PowerShell module. I was able to repoint my reference to Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation in the C# project to the assembly in the MSOnline module and all is good. (The only reason I needed the reference was to be able to create a  Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement object.)

Answer (score 0):

@Oremac is mostly right - this has been superceded by the new utility MsOnline Powershell - you need to in an administrative powershell run the command

```
Install-Module MSOnline
```

Afterwards you can do Connect-MsolService and log in.

I really wish they'd make this more clear instead of a 404...

The command lovingly spews out that this isn't a trusted repository. Why Microsoft???